# How to export all notes in OS X/iOS Notes.app?

Tags: macos, dropbox, osx-mountain-lion, ios, apple-notes

I used to take all my notes on my iPhone and iPad in Notes.app. I recently switched and take all my notes using various text editors and store the notes in my Dropbox. However, my old notes I used to take in Notes.app are stuck. I am on OS X 10.8 so I have the desktop version of Notes.app but I am still not seeing an easy way other than plain-old fashioned copy & paste.

Any help?

Comment: I just answered this [question][1] - It can be used as a follow up to the answer given.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/a/486217/151055

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a Gmail account, you can move your notes to it in Notes.app. You can then move them to some other folder in Gmail's web interface. After that, select the notes in Mail.app and export them as plain or rich text.

Comment: Thank you very much! All of these instructions helped except the last one. I can't figure out how to export emails as .txt files.

Comment: You can change the format in the Save As sheet.